# Is "song spoiler" a correct word?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

There is a friend of mine who sings the song, she isn't a professional singer. It's just that she likes singing. But she ruins the lyrics, comes up with her own, she sings one stanza correctly but, make up the second on her own. So my question is , what will she be called? A "song spoiler/ ruin-er" ?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a coined word for this and really, it's entirely opinion-based.  Maybe she (and others) think she's clever and awesome! :-)

Comment: no what she does is add funny words to it, to make everyone laugh

Comment: @ArdisEll So *satirical* or *parody*?

Comment: so there's no such word as song spoiler?

Comment: In my ears, a song spoiler sounds like you accidentally reveal the song to someone who wasn't supposed to know it yet.

Comment: @MrLister Goldfish shoals nibbling, on my toes?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Fun! Fun! FUn! In The Sun! Sun! Sun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find the phrase when I searched it online. I wonder if this is a newly coined phrase :). But then, people do use it when they hear someone sing a song so badly that they decide to run away !!!

In this case, the singer seems to be very creative. Probably, it is a case of a 'lyrics spoiler' and not 'song spoiler' on the whole.

Comment: O yes, lyrics spoiler, seems a right word. Sorry I'm not a native English speaker, i find it hard to convey what i'm trying to ask, but you helped me .Thankyou :)

Comment: People will most likely know what you mean if you refer to her as a "lyric spoiler", @ArdisEll.  For what it's worth, I found that "Parodist" is a "real" name for this person, whether it be someone who writes parodies based on written works or songs.

Answer (score 1):

Someone who does this professionally is a *satirist* or a *parodist*.  It's worth noting that American musician "Weird" Al Yankovic has become rich, famous and beloved for this activity.

However, if you want a general word for someone who willfully commits crimes against aesthetics (because he or she doesn't care!) there is a word for that: *philistine.*

It's not used commonly, and it isn't specific to music/lyrics, but it conveys the tone of disapproval you seem to be looking for.

Comment: yeah, you got that right. But is there any slang for it too?